# How to write codeigniter code for mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written some codeigniter code for below mentioned query. I need to find out if this is right or wrong.

**Mysql code –**

```
Select sum(profit) from budget_tbl where reg_date like ‘2021-%’;
```

**Codeigniter - Model**

```
function select_profit()
    {
      $this->db->select_sum("budget_tbl.profit");
       $this->db->from("budget_tbl");
       $this->db->like(‘reg_date,'2021-','after');
        $qry=$this->db->get();
       return $qry -> result();    

    }
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Shouldn't some simple tests help to check this?

Comment: Yes this is right go ahead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.